# Who is  looking at my Facebook profile or pictures?

Tags: facebook, privacy

Can a Facebook application or anyone track that information? Some applications advertise this feature. I'm not sure whether I can trust them.

Answer (score 20):

No.

http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14357

> Facebook does not allow users to track profile views or see statistics on how often a particular piece of content has been viewed and by whom without your consent.
>
> If an Application claims to provide this functionality, you can report an application for abuse by going to the application’s About page and clicking "Report Application" at the bottom of the page, or by clicking "Report" at the bottom of any canvas page within the application.

Comment: Do you have any idea "why not"? The linkedin guys don't have much fuss over this kind of *power*..

Answer (score 4):

Well, You can use Google Analytics. There are many apps available on Facebook. I have added some of them to my profle page and added Google Analytics code in that. Now I can view the number of views of the profile.

Comment: can you be a little more elobrate and give us links to the particular facebook apps you use and also may the Google Analytics Code that you use in them? Please.